# Can edit map in Rviz?

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I want to edit a saved map in rviz, for example: add a line or erase some noise points. Can anyone have some idea?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310652/can-edit-map-in-rviz?/) by [yueweiliang](https://answers.ros.org/users/28206/yueweiliang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-12-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot use rviz to edit saved maps, but you can edit the pgm files in Gimp, Pinta or another image editor.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yueweiliang](https://answers.ros.org/users/28206/yueweiliang/) on 2018-12-14**:
Thx for reply. Should this function(map editor) can be implemented by building a new plugins of rviz?I now try to make it in rviz.Can you give me some advice?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-12-14**:
You might be able to do it, but you will probably have a hard time.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-12-14**:
The interactive elements of Rviz are not good for image editing, so you will probably have to work hard to make a good user interface.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-12-14**:
The ROS nodes which can publish the map (gmapping, map_server and others) are not designed to receive updates, so you will need to come up with a different way to publish and save the updated map.

**Comment by [yueweiliang](https://answers.ros.org/users/28206/yueweiliang/) on 2018-12-14**:
ok, thx, I just want to edit the saved map to add something like glass walls、some tables that lasers can't detect and other things like these.So the function for me, it's just a image editor in Rviz.I'll try, thx for your time and advice.